# System.nanoTime and System.currentTimeMillis()

Tags: java

I am using JDK8 on Windows and JDK8 on Linux

1. When I run `System.nanoTime()/System.currentTimeMillis()` on windows， the result is `49`,

> ```
> System.nanoTime(): 74786833960332
>
> System.currentTimeMillis():1507786236263
> ```

2. When run it on Linux, the result is `26236`

> ```
> System.nanoTime(): 39560110918205325
>
> System.currentTimeMillis():1507786262105
> ```

I am confused with the result, that the two values are different so much.

Also, I thought that nanoTime is `1,000,000` times milliseconds, so that the two values above both look wrong to me(that is, both of them should be approximately 1000000)

Comment: why dont you try outputting each value individually along with your calculation and see what you get..  post the results here for more help

Comment: you see, the outputting values don't make any help when the people answer this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Java System documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html):

> [System.nanoTime] Returns the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds.

This means `System.nanoTime()` returns the elapsed running time of the JVM in nanos, whereas `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the time in milliseconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.

This results in a non-consistent nanoTime over each run.

Comment: Thanks @gery1000, the perfect answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to `System.nanotime()` docs it is not `system time` in nanoseconds and it is not related to `System.currenTimeMillis`. It is platform dependent (this is why the difference) nanoseconds generator and it is used for measuring time elapsed between two invocations.

Answer (score 5):

## Apples and Oranges

[`System.nanotime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--) has nothing to do with current date and time-of-day. Its purpose is for calculating *elapsed* time.

Your math and your comparison to [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) makes no sense at all. The two functions are incomparable.

Read the documentation before posting to Stack Overflow.

For date-time handling you should not be using the `System` class at all. Instead use the industry-leading java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

- If you want current moment in UTC, call `Instant.now()`.
- If you want current moment in a time zone, call `ZonedDateTime.now`.

In Java 9 and later, both classes use a new implementation of `Clock` to capture the current moment in a resolution up to nanoseconds. But keep in mind that mainstream computers lack a hardware clock with such fine sensitivity. Microseconds is likely the finest resolution you'll see in the real world as of 2017.

Comment: It seems like you're annoyed with that question. If that so, you shouldn't bother yourself to answer it..

Comment: @EugeneAlexeev I'm not annoyed at all. Happy to help where I can. I believe you are reading too much into my Answer. If there is specific wording that is rude/offensive, please point it out.